# Копирование структур в Си

Tags: c, массивы, struct

Есть массив структур который нужно заполнить:

```
typedef struct {
  int size;
  char** key;
  char** value;
} MATCHING[somesize];
      ||
MATCHING t[l.size];
```

заполняется через цикл в котором обьявляется такая же структура

```
MATCHING t[l.size];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < l.size; i++) {
    MATCHING tmp = getTask(id_task, id_author, id_performer);
  }
```

`id_task, id_author, id_performer` - данные необходимые для работы функции

Через оператор присваивания `=` не получается корректно. Каждый элемент массива становится равен структуре которая была при последней итерации цикла.
Пробоал еще так копировать:

```
MATCHING copyMap(const MATCHING l) {
    MATCHING* tmp = (MATCHING*)malloc(sizeof(l));
    tmp->size = l.size;
    for (int i = 0; i < l.size; i++) {
      strcpy(tmp->key[i], l.key[i]);
      strcpy(tmp->value[i], l.value[i]);
    }
    return *tmp;
}
```

но на strcpy SIGSEGV

Как правильно нужно копировать?

Comment: Что-то невнятное написано. Тип `MATCHING` - это уже сам по себе массив. Далее объявляется `MATCHING t[l.size];`, то есть `t` - это массив массивов, т.е. двумерный массив. К чему это? И, разумеется. компилироваться присваивание массивов `MATCHING tmp = getTask(` не может в принципе. Вы же нам рассказываете сказки про "Каждый элемент массива становится равен...". Ваш код не будет компилироваться вообще, поэтому о каком "становится равен" или `SIGSEGV` вы рассказываете - не ясно. Перестаньте выдумывать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Странный какой-то у Вас цикл присваивания... Может быть Вы имели в виду так:

```
MATCHING t[l.size];

  for (size_t i = 0; i < l.size; i++) {
    t[i] = getTask(id_task, id_author, id_performer);
  }
```

Comment: В этом случае `t[i]` - это массив. Как вы собираетесь присваивать массивы?

Comment: Я пробовал так присваивать, но результат один и тот же. 
У каждого из элементов массива будут равны соответствующие поля. Т.е. они все ссылаются на один адрес в памяти.

Comment: @Rodion Ну тогда надо проверять, что именно возвращает *getTask()* Скорее всего - один и тот же адрес. И тогда проблема не в присвоении, а функции *getTask()*.

Comment: @Sergey Да проблема была в функции getTask(). Спасибо